# números faltantes de un array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

He echo un conteo de un array, [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 8] me arroja el resultado de abajo, quiero que me indique los números que faltan por salir, del 0 han salido 4, seguiría el 1 pero como no existe lo omite, quisiera que apareciera ["1",0] como correspondería. o debería también aparecer ["9",0] porque el conteo se ha hecho del 0 al 9.

```
0: (2) ["0", 4]
1: (2) ["2", 1]
2: (2) ["3", 2]
3: (2) ["4", 1]
4: (2) ["6", 1]
5: (2) ["8", 1]
```

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const datos = [["0", 4],
               ["2", 1],
               ["3", 2],
               ["4", 1],
               ["6", 1],
               ["8", 1]];
//obtengo el utimo valor
const arrayLength = parseInt(datos[datos.length-1][0])
//creo un array que va de 0 a N valores.
const newArray= Array(arrayLength + 1 ).fill(0)
//obtengo su keys, como es un arreglo va a retornar.. 0,1,2,3 etc
const myArray=[...Object.keys(newArray)]
//reccoro el arreglo
const dato=myArray.map(idx=>{
  //busco el dato, en el caso de no existir retorno su index con el valor 0
  return datos.find(i=>i[0]==idx) || [idx,0]
})
console.log(dato)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira este código:

```js
const datos = [["0", 4],
               ["2", 1],
               ["3", 2],
               ["4", 1],
               ["6", 1],
               ["8", 1]];
                       
// Busque el último indice de su arreglo => en este caso es ['8', 1]
// Y extraiga el '8'
const ultimo = datos[datos.length - 1][0];

// Itere hasta el ultimo elemento inclusive
for (let i = 0; i <= ultimo; i++) {
  // Revise si el elemento actual esta en el arreglo (use == ya que compara string con number)
  const index = datos.findIndex(d => d[0] == i);
  if (index >= 0) {
    // Si se ha encontrado el elemento imprimalo
    console.log(datos[index]);
  }else {
    // Si el elemento no es encontrado (como es el caso de "1", "5" y "7")
    console.log([String(i), 0]);
  }
}
```